# Why is it said that centroids and geometric medians correspond to L2 and L1 central tendencies?

Tags: terminology, central-tendency, norm

I'm reading an article on Wikipedia about [central tendency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_tendency#Solutions_to_variational_problems) and I'm confused about why it states that centroids correspond to L2 central tendencies and geometric medians L1.

For samples $x_i$, The centroid is the point $c$ that minimizes this:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N ||x_i-c||_2^2
$$

and the geometric median $m$ minimizes:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N||x_i-m||_2
$$

Latter is the sum of 2-norms, and former the sum of squared 2-norms. So where does L1 get into any of this and how does centroid minimize L2 distances?

Also, what's marginal median then? A marginal median $m_m$ is a vector of per-axis medians and it minimizes this:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N ||x_i - m_m||_1
$$

Isn't that the sum of 1-norms?

Comment: Write the formula for the geometric median in terms of the vector $(||x_1-m||,||x_2-m||,\ldots,||x_N-m||).$  It is a norm: which one?

Comment: So looks like geometric median minimizes a 1-norm of an N-dimensional vector populated by 2-norms of differences? That would mean that marginal median minimizes a 1-norm of a vector of 1-norms, and centroid minimizes a 2-norm of 2-norms. Basically I was looking at the "inner" norm while statisticians usually refer to the "outer" one?